# Selecionar linhas distintas no SQL, adicionando exclusão com chaves diferentes

Tags: sql

Tenho duas tabelas, uma contém a `chave primária`, e a outra pega essa chave na coluna `post_id`. Na segunda coluna, ela pode repetir por várias vezes com o mesmo `post_id`.

Preciso pegar a segunda tabela, todas as linhas distintas (únicas). Mas ela deve excluir o ID que possua na coluna `meta_key` a palavra "tracking_code"

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.ID = m.post_id
WHERE 
(p.post_status = "wc-processing" AND p.post_type = "shop_order") AND m.meta_key != "tracking_code"
```

Eu tenho 2 problemas o código acima:

1º - Eu preciso que o DISTINCT traga todas as colunas wp_posts.

2º - O uso do DISTINCT em uma coluna especifica, em WHERE eu seto a exclusão da chave "**tracking_code**". Mas como existem outros `post_id` repetidos e que não contenham a palavra `tracking_code`, ele acaba retornando a chave primária. Eu precisava de algo como: tem a palavra "**tracking_code**", não pode selecionar este ID, independente de outras linhas repetidas não terem.

Tabela wp_posts

```
_____________________________________
|  ID  |  post_status  | post_type  |
|  1   | wc-processing | shop_order |
|  2   | wc-processing | shop_order |
|  3   |    wc-fail    | shop_order |
|  4   | wc-processing | shop_order |
```

Tabela wp_postmeta

```
_______________________________________________________
|  post_id |          meta_key       |   meta_value   |  
|     1    | _correios_tracking_code |  PM353535353BR |
|     1    |          _codex         |      Elite     |  
|     2    | _correios_tracking_code |                |
|     2    |          _codex         |      Elite     |
|     4    |          _teste         |      Teste     |
|     4    |          _codex         |      Elite     |
```

Comment: *"Tenho duas tabelas, uma contém a chave primária, e a outra pega essa chave na coluna post_id. Na segunda coluna, ela pode repetir por várias vezes com o mesmo post_id."*, não fica mais fácil postar o modelo das tabelas? :)

Comment: *"Mas ela deve excluir o ID que possua na coluna meta_key a palavra "tracking_code"* pode tentar um `where not exists` com uma subquery quer retorne esses IDs

Comment: @RicardoPontual Atualizado, grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O Resultado final foi:

```
select * from wp_posts u where u.ID in (
SELECT DISTINCT(p.ID)
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.ID = m.post_id
WHERE 
(p.post_status = "wc-processing" AND p.post_type = "shop_order") AND 
 NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta  m2  WHERE m2.post_id = m.post_id  AND m2.meta_key = "tracking_code" )
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Veja se com a clausula NOT EXISTS aplicada conforme a query abaixo resolve.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM wp_posts p 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.ID = m.post_id
WHERE 
(p.post_status = "wc-processing" AND p.post_type = "shop_order") AND
NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM wp_postmeta  m2  WHERE m2.meta_key = m.meta_key 
AND m2.meta_key = "tracking_code")
```

Comment: Foi quase. Tive que mudar a para: ´m2.post_id = m.post_id´ ao invés de ´meta_key´ . O único problema é DISTINCT *, ele não funciona, tenho que mudar para ´p.ID´ . Há alguma forma deu trazer todas as colunas distintas, sem setar uma a uma?

Comment: Eu confundi meta_key pelo id.  Não sei se seria possível um comando distinct sem determinar as colunas.

Comment: Entendo. Será, quando eu implementar no php, ele vai retomar toda a linha? ou apenas a coluna ID? É possível fazer um novo select com estes IDs "DISTINCT p.ID", buscando o resto das colunas? pois no meu caso elas podem ser dinâmicas.

Comment: Você poderia fazer isso. Uma vez que possui o p.Id seria possível através de uma nova consulta buscar as outras colunas.